# django bootstrap3_datetime not working on model form

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, django-forms

I'm new in Django and I would like to have use for my date field a date time picker.
I tried bootstrap3_datetime and it seems to be working well for my form, but it is not working with my ModelForm!

Here is my code

form.py

```
class AutistiForm(forms.Form):
     nome = forms.CharField(label='Nome Autista', max_length=50, required=False)
     data_inizio = forms.DateField(widget=DateTimePicker(options="format":"DD-MM-YY","pickTime":"False"}))
     data_fine = forms.DateField(widget=DateTimePicker(options={"format":"DD-MM-YY","pickTime":"False"}))


class ServiziForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Servizi
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'data': DateTimePicker(options={"format":"DD-MM-YY",                                            "id":"id_data",  "pickTime":"True"}),}
```

autisti.htlm---> Here it is working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    {{ form.media }}
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
{% for autista in queryAutisti %}
    {{ autista.autista }}
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

servizi.html---> here it is not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    {{ form.media }}

</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="OK" class="btn-default">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for your answers!!

Comment: When you say "not working", what do you mean. Are there any js errors in the console?

Comment: No, there are no errors in the console. for "not working" i mean that when i click on the button the date widget doesn't showup!
Inspecting the html code in the browser  it does not add the script for the widget! Should i try adding them by hand?

Comment: Seams like the {{ form.media }} in the servizi.html doesn't link the static files

Comment: did you end up solving this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Yes i solved it doing this:
`class SelezioneData(forms.Form):
    data = forms.DateField(widget=DateTimePicker(options={"format": "DD-MM-YYYY","pickTime": False}, attrs={'onchange':"this.form.submit()"})) `

I dont know if it will work on a model form, has been too long since i've finished this project to remember the details. sorry

Comment: Or better you can assign an id to the date filed of the form and then use the jquery date time picker adding a little bit of javascript at the bottom of the page.

Lets say you do `attrs={'id=picker'}` in the form definition and then in your html you do `$('#picker').datetimepicker(
                        {
                            dateFormat : 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                            timepicker:false,
                            lang : 'it',

                        });`